# Deploying multiple Google Cloud Functions from same repo

Tags: google-cloud-functions

The documentation for Google Cloud Functions is a little vague - I understand how to deploy a single function that is contained within `index.js` - even in a specific directory, but how does one deploy multiple cloud functions which are located within the same repository?

AWS Lambda allows you to specify a specific file and function name:

```
  /my/path/my-file.myHandler
```

Lambda also allows you to deploy a zip file containing only the files required to run, omitting all of the optional transitive npm dependencies and their resources.  For some libraries (eg Oracle DB) including `node-modules/**` would significantly increase the deployment time, and possibly exceed storage limits (it does on AWS Lambda).

The best that I can manage with Google Cloud Function deployment is:

`$ gcloud alpha functions deploy my-function \
    --trigger-http
    --source-url https://github.com/user-name/my-repo.git \
    --source-branch master \
    --source-path lib/foo/bar
    --entry-point myHandler`

...but my understanding is that it deploys `lib/foo/bar/index.js` which contains `function myHandler(req, res) {}` ...and all dependencies concatenated in the same file?  That doesn't make sense at all - like I said, the documentation is a little vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current deployment tool takes a simple approach.  It zips the directory and uploads it.  This means you (currently) should move or delete `node_modules` before executing the command if you don't wish for them to be included in the deployment package.  Note that, like lambda, GCF will resolve dependencies automatically.

As to deployment, please see: `gcloud alpha functions deploy --help`

> **Specifically:**
>
> ```
> --entry-point=ENTRY_POINT
>          The name of the function (as defined in source code) that will be
>          executed.
> ```

You might opt to use the --source flags to upload the file once, then deploy the functions sans upload.  You can also instruct google to pull functions from a repo in the same manner.  I suggest you write a quick deployment script to help you deploy a list of functions in a single command.

Comment: FYI the behavior of uploading code with `gcloud` has now changed; `node_modules` is no longer uploaded by default.

Comment: Can we put same `entry-point` on multiple functions?
Like `test1.js with entry point Main` and `test2.js with entry point Main`?